# Amazon API how to get IPs from LB?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Could someone prompt me on how to get IPs addresses of LB using AWS API?

I can get a list of LBs using `aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers`

then I can get a dns name of necessary LB `"DNSName": "something.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"`

But I can't get IPs of this domain.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get list of LBs `aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers`
2. Using get LBs name `jq -r '.LoadBalancers[] | .LoadBalancerName')`
3. Then get DNS for LB `jq -r '.LoadBalancers[] | select(.LoadBalancerName==LB-name) | .DNSName'`
4. Get IPs by DIG `$(dig +short DNSName A)`